# ¿Es redundante decir "estar presente"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, sintaxis

A veces tengo la sensación que recargamos las frases para darles más tesón, más supuesto rigor que acaba complicándolas (¿veis? yo mismo acabo de hacerlo). Entre ellas, últimamente oigo *estar presente*:

> El presunto autor del crimen dijo que él no *estaba presente* en el lugar de los hechos cuando bla bla bla.

Para mí, esto es básicamente decir:

> El presunto autor del crimen dijo que él no *estaba* <s>presente</s> en el lugar de los hechos cuando bla bla bla.

Pues *estar* ya tiene suficiente carga de significado para indicar por sí solo el hecho de hallarse en un lugar dado.

¿Estoy en lo cierto? ¿Hay casos en los que es necesario decir *estar presente* y su significado cambia respecto *estar* a secas?

Comment: En algunos casos yo diría que refuerza, estar presente indica que has presenciado algo, que no solo estás existiendo en un lugar sin más sino que te enteras de lo que pasa. Pensaba escribir una respuesta pero tengo algunas dudas, no lo veo muy claro.

Comment: @blonfu correcto, incluso el hecho de que parezca o sea una redundancia puede ser una herramienta para reforzar ese matiz. Si eso es lo que se busca, la redundancia está justificada a mí parecer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En determinados actos, una persona puede estar de dos formas: presente o representada. Por ejemplo, en una reunión, una asamblea, una firma de contrato...

Así, por ejemplo, en el acta de la asamblea de una asociación se puede escribir:

> Están presentes los socios [...] y representados los socios [...].

Por otro lado, al pasar lista se suele contestar *Presente* cuando una persona oye su nombre. De ahí que quienes han contestado *están presentes* y los demás *están ausentes*.

De estos casos y otros similares se puede haber generalizado el uso redundante de *estar presente* incluso cuando no es necesaria esta precisión, como el ejemplo de la pregunta.

Comment: Una respuesta interesante. El caso de estar presente y estar representado me convence, mas no así el de pasar lista: se puede decir que los que han contestado _están_ y los que no _no están_, no es necesario usar la palabra _presente_.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Desde luego, no sería necesario, pero sí son expresiones utilizadas. Acabo de buscar *"está presente" "está ausente"* en Google y me da más de 200 000 coincidencias.

Comment: Por incordiar un poco: se puede "estar" en un sitio y _estar ausente_ a la vez, en el sentido de estar distraido.

Comment: El caso de contestar _presente_ yo creo que es simplemente una formalidad. No queda muy formal que un profesor en una clase, o un director en una reunión, pregunte por Pablito o Don Pablo y el susodicho conteste: "_¡Estoy!_". Ciertamente no sería incorrecto, estar está, pero queda un poco confianzudo. Probablemente lo tenemos grabado así desde niños, al menos aquellos a los que nos pasaban lista en clase :P

Comment: Recuerdo ahora la canción *La de la mochila azul*, en la que Pedrito Fernández se lamentaba de *Cuando oí pasar la lista y ella no estuvo presente*.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que más bien sigue la forma gramática del verbo. Por ejemplo "estar dormido", "estar ausente", "estar pendejo". De modo que aunque el verbo estar sirva para denotar que existía en ese momento en particular, al agregar "presente" se formaliza en que estado existía en ese momento y lugar. Igual y se vuelve redundante si lo analizas muy de cerca, pero así es el lenguaje.